# Как в Django сделать роутинг для доменов 3-го и 4-го уровня?

Tags: python, django, backend

Хочу сделать роутинг на основе заголовка Host в Django, например чтобы если пользоветель ввел example.domain.com это была одна страница, а если test.example.domain.com то другая.

Comment: поставь какой-нибудь https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: а на чистом django это невозможно реализовать?

Comment: @VladRife на гитхабе либы выше строк 100-200 кода, если надо, можешь просто перенести те части, которые тебе нужны :)

Comment: а чем это не чистый django? в теории можно, тебе нужно просто посмотреть, когда django ищет урл, перехватывать request, смотреть на host и подменять urlpatterns (в теории).

Comment: вот даже если юзать эти либы, то как проверить роботу на локалке?

Comment: скопипасти там строчек 20 для минимального примера.
проверить на локалхосте через файл etc/hosts